# Integer conversion to double in C yielding zero values

Tags: c, math, casting

I originally had a function that uses pow(), and I noticed it was returning zero values every time. While debugging it, I found that this seems to be the source of the problem:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int foo(int n)
{
        printf("%d is number passed in \n", n);
        double base = (double) n;
        printf("%d is base \n", base);
        printf("%d is power\n", pow(base ,2));

        return (1/2 *( pow( (double) n, 2)));

}
```

If I call foo on *any* integer value (say, 8), the second printf statement prints zero every time. (And of course, the third one does as well). Shouldn't conversion of double to int be straightforward?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got several things wrong.

First of all, you're using the `%d` specifier in `printf`, but you're passing to it a `double` value; for `double`s, you should use `%f`<sup>1</sup>, otherwise the `printf` will try to interpret the bytes of the `double` as an `int`, leading to unexpected results (in your case 0).

Notice that this kind of error is usually noticed by recent compilers with warning level high enough.

Moreover, in the return statement you wrote

```
1/2 *( pow( (double) n, 2))
```

This expression will always yield zero, because of the `1/2` factor. Both `1` and `2` are `int`s, thus an integer division is performed, and obviously it results in 0, that kills the whole expression.

Solution: change the `1/2` to `1/2.` (where `2.` denotes 2 as a `double` value, which promotes the operation to a floating-point division), or simply replace it with `0.5`, or (even simpler) perform a division by two at the end of the expression.

---

1. Trivia: I always had the doubt that `%f` was for `float`, and something else was used for `double`s; instead, it turns out that there's no specifier for `float`s, since they are automatically converted to `double`s when passed to a function as "variable arguments" (so this applies to `printf`).

Comment: Thanks for that - it's been a while since I used C, and Python got me spoiled (on both fronts)!

Answer (score 0):

1. [Your version](http://ideone.com/KNLpZ)
2. [with correct conversion specifications](http://ideone.com/mwtY5)
3. [with no casts](http://ideone.com/BHL5k)
4. [with 1.0 in the final return](http://ideone.com/PSQx2)

Answer (score 0):

```
    printf("%g is base \n", base);
    printf("%g is power\n", pow(base ,2));
```

Your second problem is that you're doing this:

```
    return (1/2 *( pow( (double) n, 2)));
```

But have defined your function to return an `int`. You need to define it to return `double` and not use integer math there :)

Answer (score 0):

to output a double in c via printf, you should use %g or %lf (lf stands for "long float" which is a double, in fact float stands for single precision :D )
%g truncate to the least significant number, %lf do not.
You can even use something like
%.20g, so you are asking to write the number with 20 decimal number after dot (or comma).

If you want to get a float result from your function, you shoud change the function declaration to

```
double foo(int n)
```

I suggest to change the return line to this

```
return (0.5 * pow( (double) n, 2)));
```

0.5 is the right way to write 1/2 in floating point.

But if you only want an integer, then you should do this:

```
return ((int)pow( (double) n, 2)/2);
```

In fact pow return a double, and you should cast it to integer

Hope that's usefull :)